# Render italic text in pygame

Tags: python, fonts, pygame

I want to write italic text with pygame. The pygame.font documentation says that one shouldn't use set_italic() and rather load a true italic font. I checked the fonts available to pygame and there weren't any that said "italic" in the name or anything. So I was wondering how I can find out what fonts I use for writing italic text or load them, because I don't know how they're called.

Comment: You may want to read the documentation for [pygame.font.match_font()](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.match_font)

Comment: @leaf So with this I found out, that I have italic fonts and that they seem to have an additional i in their name, e.g. "ariali". But when I use these fonts the text is just a bit smaller and not really italic (inclined). I tried this with different fonts...